# Is there any way to upload datasets to Google Drive in Colab?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am working on an AI project. I am trying to upload Common Crawl to my Google One plan.

I am having issues uploading datasets to Google Drive.

**Using built-in Google Drive mounting**

It didn't upload my Common Crawl dataset to the *training_data* folder.

**Using** `gupload`

I keep getting `google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google_auth_httplib2._Response object at 0x7e057ce93dc0>)`

Comment: May I ask for the block of code responsible for the upload? By any chance you are using a service account?